# How to determine tcp port used by Windows process in C#

Tags: c#, tcp

Is there a managed class/method that would provide the TCP port number(s) used by a particular Windows processes?

I'm really looking for a .NET equivalent of the following CMD line:

```
netstat -ano |find /i "listening"
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Except for PID, take a look this:

```
IPGlobalProperties ipProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();

IPEndPoint[] endPoints = ipProperties.GetActiveTcpListeners();
TcpConnectionInformation[] tcpConnections = 
    ipProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections();

foreach (TcpConnectionInformation info in tcpConnections)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Local: {0}:{1}\nRemote: {2}:{3}\nState: {4}\n", 
        info.LocalEndPoint.Address, info.LocalEndPoint.Port,
        info.RemoteEndPoint.Address, info.RemoteEndPoint.Port,
        info.State.ToString());
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Source: [Netstat in C#](https://timvw.be/2007/09/09/build-your-own-netstat.exe-with-c/)

A bit more research bring this: [Build your own netstat.exe with c#](http://www.timvw.be/build-your-own-netstatexe-with-c/). This uses P/Invoke to call `GetExtendedTcpTable` and using same structure as `netstat`.

Comment: And to get also the PID?

Comment: Link to "Build your own netstat" is broken. [@Konamiman's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1819388/2410234) has a working link: https://timvw.be/2007/09/09/build-your-own-netstatexe-with-c/

Comment: @EddPorter 
Update:
https://web.archive.org/web/20150520071202/http://www.timvw.be/2007/09/09/build-your-own-netstatexe-with-c/

Comment: Site still online, just more a dot: https://timvw.be/2007/09/09/build-your-own-netstat.exe-with-c But it works with WinAPI

Answer (score 2):

See here for an equivalent of netstat in C#: http://towardsnext.wordpess.com/2009/02/09/netstat-in-c/

**Update:** Link is broken, but here's an equivalent: http://www.timvw.be/2007/09/09/build-your-own-netstatexe-with-c

**Update:** The original page has been archived at the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20140923073925/http://towardsnext.wordpress.com:80/2009/02/09/netstat-in-c/).

Comment: Page was not found :(

Comment: here is working link https://timvw.be/2007/09/09/build-your-own-netstat.exe-with-c/