# Enumerate all open connections

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking

Is it possible to enumerate all open connections of the current process using .NET? (similarly to the way the netstat tool does this)

Comment: are you asking about TCP/UDP Connection?

Comment: @SALMAN KHAN, TCP would suffice for my task

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819364/how-to-determine-tcp-port-used-by-windows-process-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        IPGlobalProperties properties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
        TcpConnectionInformation[] connections = properties.GetActiveTcpConnections();
```

you have to convert this array to IEnum

Comment: Note that Array already implements `IEnumerable` - no need to convert.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the [`IPGlobalProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.aspx) class in .NET.  With an instance, you can get any of the three things that `netstat` generally shows:

- Active TCP connections, via [`GetActiveTcpConnections()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.getactivetcpconnections.aspx)
- Active TCP listeners, via [`GetActiveTcpListeners()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.getactivetcplisteners.aspx)
- Active UDP listeners, via [`GetActiveUdpListeners()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.getactiveudplisteners.aspx)

Note that there's no such thing as a "UDP connection".

Here's a simple version of netstat, using this API:

```
using System;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace NetStatNet
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var props = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();

            Console.WriteLine("  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State");

            foreach (var conn in props.GetActiveTcpConnections())
                Console.WriteLine("  TCP    {0,-23}{1,-23}{2}",
                                  conn.LocalEndPoint, conn.RemoteEndPoint, conn.State);

            foreach (var listener in props.GetActiveTcpListeners())
                Console.WriteLine("  TCP    {0,-23}{1,-23}{2}", listener, "", "Listening");

            foreach (var listener in props.GetActiveUdpListeners())
                Console.WriteLine("  UDP    {0,-23}{1,-23}{2}", listener, "", "Listening");

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```