# Find ports used by Process ID

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, wmi-query, netstat

I'm using the WMI management object searcher to find a process running on a machine and return the Process ID of that process.

What I need to do next is to find what port the process is listening on.

Is there a way to do this with WMI within C#? I came across this [How to determine tcp port used by Windows process in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819364), but it doesn't allow me to query based on PID.

I've had a good hour and a half Google session looking for a solution, help much appreciated at this stage!

Cheers
Dave

Comment: Its not pretty, but as you have discovered, `netstat` will get you that info.  You can capture the output from `netstat` and parse through it.  This is a "quick n dirty" way of doing it and I would *never* use this kind of code in production.

Comment: Yea that's unfortunate! I'm fairly new to .NET and rather liked how simple it was to pull information from the management object with SQL like queries! Cheers anyway.

Comment: http://www.timvw.be/2007/09/09/build-your-own-netstatexe-with-c/

Answer (score 1):

The WMI doesn't include any class to query the list of TCP endpoints associated to a PID, To get that info you must [interop](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/iphlpapi.getextendedtcptable) with the [`GetExtendedTcpTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365928.aspx) WinApi function.