# How I can get the bandwidth per process?

Tags: c#, c++, c, c#-4.0, visual-c++

Someone can tell me how I can get the bandwidth per process(sent bytes/receive bytes per process not per network interface) like network activity tab in resource monitor.
thank all.

Comment: Same answer as every metric in Windows, WMI.

Comment: Did you tried something??

Comment: Which language? Don't just shotgun-tag your question and hope for the best.

Comment: I try to use performance counters but I can't get the bandwidth per process.

Comment: C# or C/C++, thank for all reply.

Answer (score 0):

These links may give you an idea what you are looking for

Look at the [IP Helper API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366073(v=vs.85).aspx)

You probably also need to use some undocumented functions to [resolve ports-process info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819364/how-to-determine-tcp-port-used-by-windows-process-in-c-sharp)