# Getting al ip's

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So, i'm new to C# and visual studio and stuff. But i searched arround for how to get all ip's, Like you see in the Windows Firewall app. But I can't find any thing to get started with. I saw alot of posts about Dns, And stuff So i got this:

```
        private void ip()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // Get host name
        String strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();

        // Find host by name
        IPHostEntry iphostentry = Dns.GetHostByName(strHostName);

        // Enumerate IP addresses
        foreach (IPAddress ipaddress in iphostentry.AddressList)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(strHostName + " - " + ipaddress);
            label1.Text = sb.ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\n");
        }
    }
```

But I only get 4 ip's but i want all ip's currently connecting to my pc.
(And an i know there are alot of posts about this, but i'm searching for an answer for an beginning programmer to understand)
Could anybody help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code you show gets the IPs assigned to the current machine.

What it sounds like you want is the equivalent of running netstat on the command line (get all active connections). This question should get you started: [How to determine tcp port used by Windows process in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819364/how-to-determine-tcp-port-used-by-windows-process-in-c-sharp)

Basically you use [GetActiveTcpConnections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.getactivetcpconnections(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks i'l have a look