# How can I get the source port being used by a sql connection object?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection

I have an application that connects to a SQL Server to run some queries. It connects to port 1433, but the source port can be anything in a large range. Is there a way to capture what source port is being used for any specific `SqlConnection` object?

Comment: Programmatically in C# you mean? If not you can use something like netstat or tcpview to find out. If yes then this might be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819364/how-to-determine-tcp-port-used-by-windows-process-in-c-sharp

Comment: From a cmd.exe window you can type Netstat -a to get a list of active ports.  The default port for SQL Server is 1433 where the initial connection is made.  The server will assign a different port number to the client for data transfers.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for something programmatically so I can save the port used to a log. That link might work if it returned the PID as well so that the port could be tied to a process.